# Changing the min disk property of an image on Horizon

Tags: openstack

Is it possible to change the minimum disk property of an image using the web interface Horizon?

[image]

I know that we can [use the API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16325247/395857):

```
# The following command will change minimum ram to 2000MB and minimum disk to 1GB
glance image-update <<uuid or name of image>> --min-ram 2000 --min-disk 1
```

but I would like to perform this operation using the web interface Horizon.

Comment: What is your hesitancy towards using the API?

Comment: @EEAA The client is king. The client prefers web interfaces. My job is not to change his preferences, but find the best solutions for him.

Comment: My personal opinion: web interface are rarely, if ever, the best solution. For anyone.

Comment: @EEAA Some people don't have the time to learn the API, and using a UI can be faster to learn + harder to forget. The web interface Horizon was created for a reason. Anyone can launch a new instance in less than a minute using the web interface, few can do it with CLI. Each person has its own expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. OpenStack Horizon is a Django application. If you clone [Horizon sources](https://github.com/openstack/horizon) and check the view function in [`horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/images/views.py`](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/images/views.py), you will see that it just gets the images list via an API call.

If you still need the functionality to change disk properties, you will have to extend the images view function.